# NodeJS fetch request array map returning undefined

Tags: node.js, fetch

I start working with http request with NodeJS and I'm having a issue of the response returning undefined even though I check if it was not undefined.

```
       fetch(urlRequest, {
            method: 'post',
            body:    JSON.stringify(myJSONObject),
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': `Basic ${base64.encode(`${key.APIKey}:${key.PasswordKey}`)}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            // This IF validation is not working
            if(json.result.data !== undefined){
                json.result.data.map(async (myDT) => {
                    const x = myDT;
                    console.log(x);
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
```

The code fails in the catch with the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Why isn't the IF condition working for `json.result.data`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates json.result is undefined, so checking for json.result.data is insufficient.

Easiest solution is:

```js
json && json.result && json.result.data !== undefined
```

Depending on the rest of your environment you may be able to use null-safe navigation (`?.`, IIRC there's a Babel for this) or something like lodash `get` or wrap it up in a `Proxy`, and so on. JS is quite malleable.